# react-hook-form. typescript, custom fields config with nested input names

Tags: typescript, dynamic, nested, react-hook-form

im trying to do something like fieldsConfig for map my fields and render then by switch by type and return needed component, but i cant get value of nested property when my field name is dynamic

the problem is probably somewhere here, (solution from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502671/typescript-getting-the-type-of-object-key-inside-object-itself#answer-51503091))

```
type PossibleFields<T>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-nestedvalue-forked-xio6s?file=/src/index.ts)

```
import {
  FieldPath,
  FieldValues,
  UseControllerProps,
  UseControllerReturn
} from "react-hook-form";
```

`type FieldPath` -> link [FieldPath](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/0b540d0aa16495613ed3164468cd1915fcce4d1e/src/types/path/eager.ts#L35)

```
type FieldValues = Record<string, any>;
```

`type UseControllerProps` -> link [UseControllerProps](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/0b540d0aa16495613ed3164468cd1915fcce4d1e/src/types/controller.ts#L34)

`type UseControllerReturn` -> link [UseControllerReturn](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/0b540d0aa16495613ed3164468cd1915fcce4d1e/src/types/controller.ts#L48)

```
interface HookField<
  T extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
  K extends FieldPath<T> = FieldPath<T>
> extends UseControllerProps<T, K> {
  // tpm solution, add new key here, 
  // tName?: K;
  render?: (props: UseControllerReturn<T, K>) => void;
}

type PossibleFields<T> = FieldPath<T> extends infer K
  ? K extends FieldPath<T>
    ? HookField<T, K>
    : never
  : never;

export function hookFields<T extends FieldValues = FieldValues>(
  fields: Array<PossibleFields<T>>
) {
  // return fields.map(() => {
  // logic to render different fields by type
  // will be here
  // })
  return fields;
}

interface Values {
  test: string;
  arr: Array<{
    id: string;
  }>;
}

const consoleString = (value: string) => console.log(value);

hookFields<Values>([
  {
    name: "test",
    render: ({ field: { value } }) => {
      consoleString(value);
    }
  }
]);

[].map((k, index) => {
  hookFields<Values>([
    {
      name: `arr.0.id`,
      render: ({ field: { value } }) => {
        consoleString(value);
      }
    },
    {
      name: `arr.${index}.id` as const,
      render: ({ field: { value } }) => {
        // var value: any
        // Binding element 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)
        consoleString(value);
      }
    }
  ]);
});
```

with normal **field name**  as `string`, everything is fine and im getting field value as well

[image]

but when **field name** is generated **dynamically** i cant get valid value type, is `any`

[image]

just interesting case,  typescript understand what dynamic key is exist in array `arr.${number}.id`

```js
type GetFieldKeys<T> = T extends Array<infer K>
  ? K extends { name: string }
    ? K['name']
    : never
  : never;

[].map((k, index) => {
  const fields = [
    {
      name: `arr.0.id`,
      render: ({ field: { value } }) => {
        consoleString(value);
      },
    },
    {
      name: `arr.${index}.id` as const,
      // tpm solution, add new key here, 
      // tName: `arr.0.id`;
      render: ({ field: { value } }) => {
        consoleString(value);
      },
    },
  ];
  hookFields<Values>(fields);
  type Keys = GetFieldKeys<typeof fields>;
});
```

[image]